# SQL query linked from the same table

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I'm not really a programmer and I'm trying to make a query to sum quotes, purchase orders, and invoices by month for a given year. Some problems I've come across (trying to use specifically the query wizard) Have been linking the dates of when the 3 categories listed above occur. For example

```
InvoiceCost|InvoiceDate|QuoteCost|QuoteDate|POCost|PODate
$$$        |  Date     |  $$$    |  Date   | $$$  | Date
$$$        |  Date     |  $$$    |  Date   | $$$  | Date
```

(I hope that works)
What I want to get from a table like this is a query which sums the categories and sorts them by month. What I've gotten is the rows list all the unique combinations of dates with their category sums Via -

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Format$([Table].[invoiceDate],'mmmm yyyy') AS [invoiceDate By Month],
                   Format$([Table].[PODate],'mmmm yyyy') AS [PODate By Month],  
                   Format$([Table].[quoteDate],'mmmm yyyy') AS [quoteDate By Month],
                   Sum(Table.invoiceCost) AS [Sum Of invoiceCost], 
                   Sum(Table.POCost) AS [Sum Of POCost],
                   Sum(Table.quoteCost) AS [Sum Of quoteCost]
FROM Table
GROUP BY Format$([Table].[invoiceDate],'mmmm yyyy'), 
         Format$([Table].[PODate],'mmmm yyyy'), 
         Format$([Table].[quoteDate],'mmmm yyyy'), 
         Year([Table].[invoiceDate])*12+DatePart('m',[Table].[invoiceDate])-1,       
         Year([Table].[PODate])*12+DatePart('m',[Table].[PODate])-1, 
         Year([Table].[quoteDate])*12+DatePart('m',[Table].[quoteDate])-1;
```

I want to know some SQL "magic" that would link the date columns within the table to avoid unique date combinations.

EDIT

To be more specific,

```
<style type="text/css">
   table.tableizer-table {
   border: 1px solid #CCC; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
   font-size: 12px;} 
.tableizer-table td {
   padding: 4px;
   margin: 3px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;}
.tableizer-table th {
   background-color: #104E8B; 
   color: #FFF;
   font-weight: bold;}
</style><table class="tableizer-table">
<tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>invoiceDate</th><th>QuoteDate</th><th>PODate</th><th>sumInvoice</th><th>sumQuote</th><th>sumPO</th></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>17-Jul-13</td><td>01-Jul-13</td><td>$0.00</td><td>$0.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr>
<tr><td>30-Jul-13</td><td>01-Jan-14</td><td>31-Mar-14</td><td>$100.00</td><td>$10.00</td><td>$48.00</td></tr>
<tr><td>30-Dec-13</td><td>01-Feb-14</td><td>10-Jan-14</td><td>$615.00</td><td>$50.00</td><td>$23.00</td></tr>
<tr><td>03-Jan-14</td><td>01-Jan-14</td><td>16-Mar-14</td><td>$3.00</td><td>$100.00</td><td>$615.00</td></tr>
<tr><td>16-Jan-14</td><td>01-Jan-14</td><td>20-Feb-14</td><td>$65.00</td><td>$50.00</td><td>$156.00</td></tr>
<tr><td>03-Mar-14</td><td>24-Jan-14</td><td>24-Feb-14</td><td>$0.00</td><td>$200.00</td><td>$0.00</td></tr>
<tr><td>11-Mar-14</td><td>18-Dec-13</td><td>21-Feb-14</td><td>$3,500.00</td><td>$5,000.00</td><td>$4,000.00</td></tr>
<tr><td>13-Mar-14</td><td>01-Jan-14</td><td>11-Dec-13</td><td>$15.00</td><td>$1,000.00</td><td>$231.00</td></tr>
<tr><td>15-Mar-14</td><td>30-Jan-14</td><td>19-Feb-14</td><td>$10.00</td><td>$8,000.00</td><td>$20.00</td></tr>
<tr><td>20-Mar-14</td><td>09-Jan-14</td><td>14-Feb-14</td><td>$1,000.00</td><td>$200.00</td><td>$20,000.00</td></tr>
<tr><td>21-Mar-14</td><td>01-Mar-14</td><td>20-Feb-14</td><td>$15.00</td><td>$10,000.00</td><td>$45.00</td></tr>
</table>
```

Notice the dates in the rows make combinations. What I want to see is something like this

```
invoiceD|POD    |quoteD |SumOfinvoiceCost|SumOfPOCost|SumOfquoteCost
1-2014  |1-2014 |1-2014 |$68.00          |$23.00     |$9,560.00
12-2013 |12-2013|12-2013|$615.00         |$231.00    |$5,000.00
3-2014  |3-2014 |3-2014 |$4,540.00       |$663.00    |$10,000.00
7-2013  |7-2013 |7-2013 |$100.00         |$0.00      |$0.00
```

I've been able to get this to work by making 4 total queries ( 3 to make separate category sums by month and the 4th to link the dates together.) Is it possible for SQL to do all of that in one query or should I just make 3 separate tables in access storing the categories away from each other?

Let me know if more information is needed. 
Thanks

Comment: quel SQL ? The microsoft "version" ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? MySQL? SQLServer? PostgreSQL?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Access 2013, which I believe to be fully updated. The only SQL I use is attached to Access and I don't know what version that is.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know some SQL "magic" that would link the date columns
>   within the table to avoid unique date combinations.

To avoid unique date combinations to get the sums you can't group by all columns, you must group by only by dates:

```
SELECT invoiceDate, QuoteDate, PODate, month(invoiceDate) as month,
      sum(invoiceCost) as sumInvoice, 
      sum(QuoteCost) as sumQuote, 
      sum(SOCost) as sumSO
FROM Table
GROUP BY invoiceDate, QuoteDate, PODate, month(invoiceDate) as month
```

You don't need a `DISTINCT` clause on `SELECT`.

To group by month too, you must include that field on `select` and `group by` clauses, but if you haven't a field `month`, try using the `month()` function on one of the date fields that it has all the months values that could appear.

Comment: Running this code gives me similar results to what I had before, although the SQL is much tidier. The results still don't sum all the categories for a given month and leave unique date combination sums.

Comment: When you say "categories", what are you referring exactly? Maybe I haven't understood your question. Further, do you want the sums() for a given month? Explain it better please

Comment: Categories as in Quote, PO and Invoice and the sums for all the months is desired.

Comment: So you must include the `month` in your `select` and `group by` clauses

Comment: adding a comma after the first month and running gives, " Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'month(invoiceDate) as month'." with the last as highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this:

```
SELECT Format$(thedate,'mmmm yyyy') as MMMYYYY,
       Sum(invoiceCost) AS [Sum Of invoiceCost], 
       Sum(POCost) AS [Sum Of POCost],
       Sum(quoteCost) AS [Sum Of quoteCost]
FROM ((select invoiceDate as thedate, invoiceCost, NULL as POCost, NULL as quoteCost
        from Table
       ) union all
       (select PODate as thedate, NULL as InvoiceCost, POCost, NULL as quoteCost
        from Table
       ) union all
       (select QuoteDate as thedate, NULL as InvoiceCost, Null as POCost, NULL as quoteCost
        from Table
       )
      ) as t
GROUP BY Format$(thedate, 'mmmm yyyy')
ORDER BY min(thedate);
```

EDIT:

Access may not allow subqueries allowed in subqueries.  You can also do this with left outer join, *if* you have a list of months.  So, if I assume that all months have invoices, then you can do:

```
SELECT i.MMMYYYY,
       i.invoiceCost AS [Sum Of invoiceCost], 
       p.POCost AS [Sum Of POCost],
       q.quoteCost AS [Sum Of quoteCost]
FROM ((select Format$(invoiceDate, 'mmm yyyy') as mmmyyyy, sum(InvoiceCost) as InvoiceCost
       from Table t
       group by Format$(invoiceDate, 'mmm yyyy')
      ) i left join
      (select Format$(PODate, 'mmm yyyy') as mmmyyyy, sum(POCost) as POCost
       from Table t
       group by Format$(PODate, 'mmm yyyy')
      ) p
      on i.mmmyyyy = p.mmmyyyy
     ) left join
     (select Format$(QuoteDate, 'mmm yyyy') as mmmyyyy, sum(QuoteCost) as quoteCost
      from Table t
      group by Format$(QuoteDate, 'mmm yyyy')
     ) q
     on i.mmmyyyy = q.mmmyyyy
```

Comment: Running this code I get a "Syntax error in JOIN operation" with the first "union all" highlighted.

Comment: Running this code now gives a "Syntax Error in FROM Clause" nothing highlighted

Comment: @SneakyPanda40 . . . There was a typo with `t.*` in one of the `from` clauses.

Comment: Well, the code still doesn't work. At first it gives a "Syntax error (missing operatir) in query expression 'Format$(PODate as thedate, 'mmm yyyy')" I figured it's because of the "as thedate" tag. removing that now gives a "Circular reference caused by alias 'InvoiceCost' in query definitions Select list". Hope that helps.